# Trade-off between variable stability and discriminatory model quality

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, credit-scoring

It is very normal for data scientists and modeling professionals to be concerned with the stability of the model. It basically means that if a variable is important today, it cannot change its importance over time because this instability would be a demonstration of the model's weakness.

It is difficult to argue that stability is good. But in the area of ​​credit modeling (which produces credit scores, for example) people are cracked by stability, to the point of preferring models with less discrimination to a more stable one.

My question is what is the true utility of stability and what is the correct way to make this trade-off with the discriminatory metric of the model (KS, Gini, AUC, etc.).

I would guess (personal guess) that stability somehow ties the model to a less than ideal metric because it does not allow behaviors to change over time. If they don't really change, there will be no problems, but if the effects of the variables are changing over time, it is normal to assume that this is reflected in less stability and analysts work around this by placing simpler models or removing the variables.

Comment: When there's a shift in stability of one or more variables, it most likely means the underlying population is changing. In a credit scoring context, this could be cause for concern. It may mean your model is incorrectly predicting the level of risk for new customers. This may lead to customers being granted credit when they shouldn't be, or causing loss/capital reserves to be insufficient. On top of this, more stable models give more consistent outcomes over time, and need to be rebuilt less often.

Comment: I understand and I agree with you. But the key point is that population is changing and a stable model is only stable if it doesn't. Therefore, a stable model appears to be the model that is not influenced by population change. People are passionate about stable role models when the ideal would be to retrain for the population's new behavior.

Comment: The ideal situation would be to  build a model with the highest possible performance (discriminatory power or calibration), and rebuilding the model whenever it becomes 'unstable'. However, rebuilding a model is a significant undertaking in terms of cost, resources and regulatory requirements. I think the best way to measure the trade off between a model with good performance and model with good stability is to run them both through test environments to measure business impacts. Based on these business impacts, you can decide which route (performance or stability) is best.